# Using IF statement with Net Use

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a simple batch to map drive D or E of a remote computer. I want the batch to try mapping D drive, and if D drive is not available, then Map E.

Example,

Try mapping \server\D$\FolderName, if it returns an error, then map \server\E$\FolderName.

FolerName is a static name and will not change. However it could be in D: or E: on the remote computer.

Note: The remote computer requires a local login and the computer i'm mapping from uses domain login.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the D and E I'm referring to is on the remote computer. I can use any available drive on the computer I'm mapping from. Its just that the remote computer could either have a D or E partition. Should be something like this

net use L: \\path\D$, if this fails. Try with net use L: \\path\E$

Comment: @Aaron, can you expand on that further, it seems odd, _though not unheard of_, that `E:` will not be available, but `D:` will be. Would it not be better to check for a `E:\ ` or `D:\ ` with `If Exist` first, then run the command based on what is returned?

Comment: @Compo, yep that make sense. Will that work though if the remote computer uses different username/password? In this case, the server i'm mapping from uses domain credentials and the remote computer use local credentials.

Comment: @Aaron Your requirements keeps changing in the comments, I suggest you edit your question and add all the relevant information as it is about to be closed. You also have 2 answers below already and have not considered trying ay of them yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, *according to your latest question edit*:

```
NET USE * \\server\D$\FolderName 2>Nul || NET USE * \\server\E$\FolderName
```

Or vice versa:

```
NET USE * \\server\E$\FolderName 2>Nul || NET USE * \\server\D$\FolderName
```

*If you don't know how to add your login /password to the `Net Use` command or want to know what the asterisk, `*` means, enter `Net Use /?` at the Command prompt for usage information.*

Comment: thanks for the update. I have updated my question with more details. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

simple.

```
if exist \\someserver\d$ (
     net use * \\someserver\d$ /user:localusername password
) else (
     net use * \\someserver\e$ /user:localusername password
) else (
     echo No share available.
)
```

As per your comments, each of the `net use` statements above can have different logon credentials specified, just update accordingly.

Comment: I prefer to add a dot to directory names, as in `if not exist d:\. (...)`.

Comment: @Gerhard, yes the net use can have different logon credentials, not sure about the if statement to test the drive availability though. I tried it out in my batch, it just returns path doesn't exist. I'm able to net use with credentials to map the drive.

Comment: @Gerhard, i used the following:

if exist \\RemoteComputer\D$ (
 echo Path Exist
) else (
 Echo Path Doesn't Exist
)
Pause

It returned doesn't exist, i know for sure that the remote computer has D drive.